# Python dict from an object's attributes when __dict__ does not exist?

Tags: python

Usually I get a dict from an object attributes by using vars() or object.__ dict __ but this does not work for many objects :

When using a ZipInfo object I get :

```
In [11]: f
Out[11]: <zipfile.ZipInfo at 0x7f4c27fa9e60>
In [12]: vars(f)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-b663d4bf75ea> in <module>()
----> 1 vars(f)

TypeError: vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute
```

The only way I found to get a dict is to do :

```
In [18]: { k:getattr(f,k) for k in dir(f) if not k.startswith('_') }
Out[18]: 
{'CRC': 1070265580,
 'FileHeader': <bound method ZipInfo.FileHeader of <zipfile.ZipInfo object at 0x7f4c27fa9e60>>,
 'comment': '',
 'compress_size': 73088,
 'compress_type': 8,
 'create_system': 0,
 'create_version': 20,
 'date_time': (2017, 3, 9, 17, 11, 44),
 'external_attr': 0,
 'extra': '',
 'extract_version': 20,
 'file_size': 720193,
 'filename': u'stateCaptureData.txt',
 'flag_bits': 2056,
 'header_offset': 0,
 'internal_attr': 0,
 'orig_filename': 'stateCaptureData.txt',
 'reserved': 0,
 'volume': 0}
```

Is there a more official way ?

Comment: What do you want to do with the attributes?

Comment: do some generic treatments that can be done only on dict

Comment: That's hardly useful context; *to what end*?

Comment: Actually I am building a library managing strings, lists, dicts. I can do many things including do a grep on a specific key for a list of dicts : python-textops : http://python-textops.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html